# Get Xml from Text file which contains plain text and XML

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a text file which contains normal text and XML (contains both end tag & self closing tag).

How can i extract the xml alone from the file based on the ErrorId

```
6/13/2014 11:50:51 PM : StudentInfo : ErrorId - 6124
Below is the sample XML
<student>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>Test</Name>        (having end tag)
  <Age xsi:nil="true"/>    (self closing tag)
</student>

6/13/2014 11:50:51 PM : StudentInfo : ErrorId - 6127
Below is the sample XML
<student>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>Sample</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</student>
```

.
.
.

Here i have to get only the XML text based on the errorid
Tried by using RegEx, but no luck.

I shoulg get the output as below when i pass ErrorId as 6127

```
<student>
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>Sample</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</student>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var students = XElement.Parse("<doc>" + text + "</doc>")
     .Elements("student")
     .ToArray();
```